# How to specify that a chain of relationships implies another

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

Suppose I'm defining an OWL ontology for family relationships, and I've already defined the relationships "sister-of" and "parent-of". I'd now like to define a relationship "aunt-of" and specify that this relationship is implied by a chain of the other two. In other words: if X "sister-of" Y, and Y "parent-of" Z, then X "aunt-of" Z.

Is there a way to do this? It's similar to `owl:TransitiveProperty` but that obviously doesn't work. It's also in the same general vein as "owl:inverseOf" in terms of defining relationships among properties.

#### Edit

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to specify that one property (in this case "aunt-of") is a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) of other properties, but I still can't actually find a way to do this in OWL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming use of OWL2, you can use the [ObjectPropertyChain](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Object_Subproperties) construct (this feature was not available in OWL1). This can be expressed in RDF using Turtle as simply:

```
ex:auntOf owl:propertyChainAxiom ( ex:sisterOf ex:parentOf ) .
```

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm Do note though, that this doesn't do exactly what you asked for ("one property (in this case "aunt-of") is a composition of other properties").  This says that the composition is a *subproperty* of another.  Everytime you have `x sisterOf y . y parentOf z .` You'll get `x auntOf z`, but you *don't* get the other direction.  You can't infer from `x auntOf z` that there is some y such that `x sisterOf y . y parentOf z .`  The chain is a subproperty of the property.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks, that's a good note. Of course, that's what you would expect since in `x` may be the sister of multiple entities but they are not (in general) all the parents of `z`.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm No, it's not necessarily what you would expect.  X is the aunt of z *if and only if* a sibling of x is a parent of z.  That's what it means to be an aunt.  The subproperty chain axiom only captures one direction of that definition.  In OWL, because the subproperty chain doesn't cover both directions, even if you know that x is an aunt of z, you can't infer that there is *some* y such that x is a sister of y and that y is a parent of z.  Just knowing that x is an aunt, you can't infer that x is a sister of a parent.  You only get one direction of the *if and only if*.

Comment: To make it even more explicit:  you can assert that x is the aunt of z, and assert that z has no parent, or that x has no sibling, and things are still logically consistent, even if you have the subproperty chain axiom that (sisterOf o parentOf) is a subproperty of auntOf.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. As long as I can still explicitly assert the `aunt-of` relationship without defining the sibling/parent, I'm fine. But it's good to know.