# OWL: define relation via another relation

Tags: semantic-web, owl, modeling, relation

I'm currently learning how to use linked data and specifically how to deal with ontologies and with semantic data.
To do this I'm diving into OWL and I'm trying to model a simple work environment. For the problem I have the following to parts are of interest

- the *Employee* class
- the *Projects* class
- the *:worksOn* relation between an *Employee* and a *Project*

If I now have

```
Employee1 :worksOn Project1
Employee2 :worksOn Project1
```

is there any way to model a property *:worksWith*, such that in this example case `Employee1 :worksWith Employee2` could be derived without explicitly stating it? So basically I want to know if it is possible to define a relation via another relation?

Comment: Yes.  In OWL you'd do this with a subproperty chain.  You'd say that :worksWith is a subproperty of (inverse(:worksOn) o :worksOn).  ["How to infer isBrotherOf property between two individuals" and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19559651/1281433) have more information than you need, but definitely answer this question.  Also, [How to specify that a chain of relationships implies another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24147160/1281433).  Since inverse(:worksOn) is a property, the chain you're interested in is inverse(:worksOn) - :worksOn.

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Should I now close the question as a duplicate, or simply leave it open, because what I'm asking is pretty much answered in those questions already?

Comment: I think this is a well worded question, and may help others find that same kind of information. It's a bit simpler than those other questions too,so not quite a duplicate. The best thing might be to post and  accept a self answer when you get it all worked out.

Comment: Ok, then that's what I'll do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition of Joshua Taylor is the right one. I've tested it under [Protégé 5.0.0 beta 17](http://protege.stanford.edu/).

You have to use the [Machester OWL Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/) to define the `worksWith` object property:

```
worksOn o inverse (worksOn) subPropertyOf worksWith
```

[image]

Then using any of the reasoners ([HertmiT](http://www.hermit-reasoner.com/), [Fact++](http://owl.man.ac.uk/factplusplus/) or [Pellet](https://github.com/complexible/pellet)) you obtain the desired inference (in yellow).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! As soon as I have the possibility to try it out myself I will accept the answer